# Installing linux onto a windows 98 system

Tags: linux, windows, fedora, windows-98

I would like to install a Linux OS on a system which currently has the windows 98 OS installed but be able to use both OS's (not at the same time...obviously). I am unsure what version of Linux I would like to install as I am very new to the ideas and concepts of the Linux OS. I bought the book "Linux for dummies" (5th edition), which comes with a full version of Fedora Core but the system in question only has 128MB of ram and I do not know if this is enough to run any kind of Linux. I would greatly appreciate anyone's help with this project.

Comment: First of all, avoid all *for Dummies* books. They're typically useless. Secondly, there's Damn Small Linux, which can run on something much less (486DX2 with 16MB of RAM). However, I'd recommend ditching this project if it has no bearing on your livelihood -- you will gain very little practical experience if you succeed.

Comment: Linux runs no problem with 128MB of RAM, and you shouldn't have any issues installing on such an older system, the issue is support for "modern" GUI's (KDE/Gnome) .. the real question is though, what will you be using this for? A server, a "desktop", other nefarious deeds? .. A server should be fine to do an install without GUI, other stuff might require some finagling of the software; you'll also need to partition the drive so you can dual boot the Windows and Linux systems (easy enough with the installers) .. You could also try "live" editions that don't install anything if you're curious.

Answer (score 3):

Lubuntu 14.04 LTS requires only 128MB RAM. Lubuntu 14.04 is a Long Term Support release that will be supported by updates until April, 2017. The later releases of Lubuntu require a minimum of 512MB RAM. Lubuntu 14.04 32-bit is compatible with your computer. Download it from the official [Lubuntu/GetLubuntu/LTS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu/LTS) webpage.

Unlike many "tiny" varieties of Linux, Lubuntu 14.04 does not present the user with a challenging text based interface. Lubuntu's LXDE desktop environment is comparable to Windows XP in look and feel.

Lubuntu is similar to Ubuntu with a much more lightweight desktop environment, so to help you get started with your project I also recommend that you download the free [Getting Started with Ubuntu 14.04](https://files.ubuntu-manual.org/manuals/getting-started-with-ubuntu/14.04/en_US/screen/Getting%20Started%20with%20Ubuntu%2014.04.pdf) written by the Ubuntu Manual Team. Getting Started with Ubuntu 14.04 is a comprehensive beginners guide for the Ubuntu operating system.

- Download [Getting Started with Ubuntu 14.04](https://files.ubuntu-manual.org/manuals/getting-started-with-ubuntu/14.04/en_US/screen/Getting%20Started%20with%20Ubuntu%2014.04.pdf).
- Download [Getting Started with Ubuntu 16.04](https://files.ubuntu-manual.org/manuals/getting-started-with-ubuntu/16.04/en_US/screen/Getting%20Started%20with%20Ubuntu%2016.04.pdf)

The official Ubuntu documentation for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server is found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/).